# MEL nParticles stop rotation after collision

Tags: maya, mel

I have a simple `nParticles` been created with initial orient and rotation with some expressions, and the issue is that on collision with the ground they keep on rotating. I followed a tutorial online and I don't have a lot of experience with expressions. I'm using these expressions in the creation:

```
nParticleShape1.InitialOrient = <<rand(360),rand(360),rand(360)>> ;
nParticleShape1.RotateFactor = <<rand(10),rand(10),rand(10)>> ;
```

and in the after runtime:

```
nParticleShape1.InitialOrient += nParticleShape1.RotateFactor ;
```

How can I make them stop rotating after the collision?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple `if-else` runtime statement:

```
if (nParticleShape1.event >= 1) {
    nParticleShape1.rotatePP = <<$x, $y, $z>> ; 
    //rotation at the moment of and after the collision event...
} else {
    nParticleShape1.initialOrient += nParticleShape1.rotateFactor ; 
} ;
```